# Database Structure for a school management system (using laravel to implement the webapp)

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

1. The school has six classes A to F .
2. A student belongs to a class and a Class has many students .( student our registered to a class using class_id in the students table)
3. A Student in a class takes more than one subject ...(""here i tried using subject_id but when a student is registering for more one subject the subject_id is overwritten by the new subject_id which means the student can take only one subject which is not what i want ... i taught of putting all the subject_id in a single cell in my database table but it made no sense"")
4. Is there a way to register multiple subjects for a student in a particular class and pls how do i do it ...
5. each subject or student has a score or record system for each subject ( i mean in each subject, student takes tests and exams which used to generate the student's result 
   thank you in advance

Comment: It should be 1 class has many subject and has many student,1 subject has many student

Comment: It should be 1 class has many subject and has many student, 1 subject has many student and belong to a class, 1 student belongs to a classes and subjects. Hope that helps you.

Comment: thank you so very much... but how can i relate it to the student's exam or test score for different subjects they are taking

Comment: but if i register a subject for a particular student it stores the subject id for in the student's table but if i register a new subject the id is overwritten and the previous subject registered is no longer available for the student

Comment: how can i store multiple subject id in a single database cell

Comment: You should relate like this. 

1 subject has many student_exam / test_score
1 student has many student_exam / test_score
1 student_exam / test_score belongs to subject and student